# Calculo de ítems de una columna

Tags: python

¿Cómo sumar los distintos ítems en una columna?

Cómo el código indica, tenía una lista donde extraje ´activity´, luego la asigne a una variable **y** , ´activity´ consta de los siguientes items, standing, walking, laying, etc. Quiero saber la suma de cada item de ´activity´ la cual esta asignada a la variable **y**.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://github.com/herrfz/dataanalysis/blob/master/data/samsungData.csv?raw=true'
df = pd.read_csv(url,index_col=0,parse_dates=[0])




%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import seaborn as sns; sns.set 
import numpy as np 




df




y = (df[['activity']]) 




y




x = df.loc[:, df.columns != 'activity']

x
```

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende. En Python no existe nada llamado columna, existen diccionarios, listas, tuplas, variables, objetos, clases...

Comment: Bienvenido a SO ES c: digo lo mismo que el comentario arriba del mio. Tu pregunta es sobre una consulta de SQL?

Comment: Bueno si, de una lista tenía ´activity´, la extraje y le asigne una variable ´y´, ahora los componentes de la variable ´y´  son standing, laying, walking, etc. Entonces quiero saber cuantos componentes de standing hay en la variable, cuantos de walking, etc.

Comment: Podrías agregar el código donde haces eso por favor?

Comment: Me referia a que edites la pregunta y agregues el código allí. Es mas facil ayudarte de esa forma.

Comment: Ya agregue el código a la pregunta

Comment: Ya esta, le di 4 espacios.

Answer (score 0):

no se entiende muy bien la pregunta pero entiendo que debes hacer un filtrado por actividades y luego sumarlas, en ese caso puedes empezar por:

```
filtrado = df[df["activity"]=="walking"]

filtrado.count(axis='activity')
```

creo que así puedes probar. debe haber una manera mas elegante pero lo que capto hasta ahora es eso